# sum pandas column by condition with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, sum, pandas-groupby

I have large data frame, I need to sum 'view' column for the for time period  from 'view_day' column.
The data frame looks like:

```
size = 400
dtype = [('view_day', 'int32'), ('account', 'int32'), ('view', 'int32')]
values = np.ones(size, dtype=dtype)

dfo = pd.DataFrame(values)

dfo['view_day'] = np.random.randint(7605, 7605 + 180, dfo.shape[0])
dfo['account'] = np.random.randint(1548051, 1548051 + 10, dfo.shape[0])
dfo['view'] = np.random.randint(600, 1800, dfo.shape[0])
    view_day account        view
0   7651     1548055        1338
1   7698     1548054        1147
```

I need to create new data frame, with account as index, and sum the total view in the last 30 days. New data frame looks like:

```
accounts= dfo.account.unique()

size = len(accounts)
dtype = [('view_last_30', 'int32')]
values = np.zeros(size, dtype=dtype)
index = accounts
dfc1 = pd.DataFrame(values, index=index)
           view_last_30
1548058    sum of view of this account for the last 30 days
1548057             "
```

I manage to group and sum the data with groupby in the following way:

```
last_day= dfo['view_day'].max()
dfo['last_30'] = dfo['view_day'] > last_day- 30
gl = dfo.groupby(['account', 'last_30'])['view']
h = gl.sum()
```

I get:

```
account  last_30
1548051  False      30439
         True        6713
1548052  False      27491
         True        8477
```

How do I copy the sum's with last_30== True in to the new created data frame ?
So I will get:

```
          view_last_30
1548051    6713
1548052    8477
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [IndexSlice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) accessor:

```
In [57]: s
Out[57]:
account  last_30
1548051  False      30439
         True        6713
1548052  False      27491
         True        8477
Name: val, dtype: int64

In [58]: s.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,True]]
Out[58]:
account
1548051    6713
1548052    8477
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked well. Is there a way to get the sum of the value per row ? is there a trick to calculate them one after the other super efficiently ?

Comment: @Naomi, could you please ask a new question with the corresponding sample data set anddesired datat set? Currently it's not very clear to me...

Comment: sure, will ask a new question

Answer (score 2):

`get_level_values` then using boolean select

```
df.loc[df.index.get_level_values('last_30').values].\
       reset_index('last_30',drop=True)
Out[590]: 
         value
account       
1548051   6713
1548052   8477
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked efficiently. How do i get the False values in this method ?

Comment: adding `~` `df.loc[~df.index.get_level_values('last_30').values].\
       reset_index('last_30',drop=True)`